# Refresh materialized view time increases over times

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, materialized-views

I have a node server which refresh a PGSQL materialized view every 30s

`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY player_stats`

To allow refresh `CONCURRENTLY`, I created a unique index on one column.

`create unique index on player_stats ("playerId");`

When I run a basic `SELECT` query on my `player_stats` view just after I created it, the query takes ~900ms. However, after more than 200 refreshs, the same query takes more than 10 seconds. Important, the number of rows in `player_stats` did not change between the first and last query.

Also the refresh time increases over times. The first refresh time was 15s, the last one was more than 1 minute!

The more I do refresh the longer the queries take (`select` and `refresh`). I have no idea what is causing this issue and how I can debug/solve it.

Comment: Presumably the underlying data is changing, increasing in size.  But that is just speculation, because your question is essentially:  I have code that is getting slower over time, but I'm not going to include it in my question.

Comment: I would suggest you also ask this question at dba.stackexchange.com and add more details of the view and the underlying data.

Comment: Indeed, I've found that refreshing my view make the table size increase at every refresh. This is strange because if I just drop and recreate the view, the size smaller than the size after a few refresh but the view is created with the same data.